# What version of tar does 7-zip use?

Tags: tar, 7-zip, gnu, bsd

Does anyone know what version of tar 7zip uses for archiving/extracting?

Is it gnu tar or bsd tar... or something else?

I've googled around for an answer but can't find anything.

Comment: Out of curiosity why does the version affect your issue/problem? And what is the issue/problem?

Comment: Go look at the source code https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/15.14/

Comment: @Dave I need the tar file to be compatible with linux systems.

Comment: Ask this question on the 7-Zip support forum....https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797